# Existence of free functor to Banach spaces

Tags: ct.category-theory, banach-spaces, monads, adjoint-functors

Is there a "non-trivial" characterization of the concrete categories admitting and adjoint pair of functors $F \dashv G$ were $G$ is defined on the category **sBan** of separable Banach spaces and bounded linear maps?  (*Besdies checking if the adjoint functor theorems hold)*

Comment: What do you mean by "admitting a forgetful functor"? Do you mean admitting a functor that has a left adjoint, or something more specific?

Comment: Just that there is a free functor from **sBan** to $\mathfrak{D}$.

Comment: terms like free and forgetful do not make sense in isolation. What is your definition of "free functor"? Do you just mean "functor which has a right adjoint"

Comment: @YemonChoi I added clarrifications...

Comment: Do you have any examples in mind? Your category of Banach spaces isn't very well-behaved, I think; much better behaved is the category of Banach spaces and short maps (maps of norm $\le 1$), which e.g. is complete and cocomplete, and has the property that two Banach spaces are isomorphic iff they're isometric.

Comment: I only have the Arens-Eells construction in mind... but if need by I can definitely consider the category of separable Banach spaces with short-maps.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan as you probably know, for the category with short maps, there's a functor to Set given by "take the closed unit ball" which has as its left adjoint "form the $\ell^1$-space"

Comment: This link has some relevant discussion: https://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-25-2/25J2Castillo.pdf

Comment: @MrMMS Thanks for the link.  Indeed I have found this paper on Yemon's ncatlab page.  Relevant but still unfortunately, it doesn't contain the answer...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I guess the question can (potentially) boiled down to verifying if **sBan** is indeed cocomplete; in which case we could apply an ajoint functor theorem since **sBan** is therefore cototal...

The problem is that I'm not convinced that **sBan$_1$** would be (co)complete itself...